# PictureBox anchor not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

On my form I have a `Panel` control that contains a `PictureBox` control and a `Label` control.
[image]

The panel is not visible in the image above but it's basically the area around these two controls.

I have set the *Anchor* property of all these three controls to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right` so that they follow their parent container's re-sizing behavior.

The L abel control (*postbagfolderempty*) works properly but the PictureBox (*EMPTY!*) does not seem to be moving from its original position.

Is there an additional property I need to set?

**Update:** I changed my PictureBox's `AutoSize` property to *None*. It has started to move, but as I try to enlarge my form, it starts sinking into a white area (image below).
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @IvanStoev I want my `PictureBox` to behave exactly like my `Label`, they have the same Anchor value but they don't behave the same way.

Comment: I don't know what your label is doing, so again, what exactly are you trying to achieve? e.g. centering, etc. Note that by default label is `AutoSize`, while `PictureBox` is not, and that affects the behavior. So, for the third time, what really are you trying to achieve :)

Comment: @IvanStoev I want to centralize both of them as the user resizes the form. That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Disasterkid anchoring modifies the size, not just the position. If you want them centered -and- scaled with the form, anchoring is the right solution, if you want them only centered, then **not anchoring** is actually the right solution: set your anchors to `None`

Comment: You've probably set label `TextAlign` to center, that's why you think they work differently. Activate temporarily borders for both controls and you'll see they behave the same. There is no `Anchor` setup that performs centering - you need to write a code for that.

Comment: @IvanStoev actually, no anchoring, if the controls are centered at design time, does keep them centered in runtime :-) It does not center by itself, definitely, but it does keep them centered

Comment: @Jcl That will keep them at the same location, so when the container Width changes, they will not be centered anymore.

Comment: @IvanStoev nope, that's what Top/Left does (it anchors the location to the parent disregarding its width/height). If it's not anchored, the location will change depending on the container size (since it's not anchored anywhere). Try it

Comment: @Jcl Oops, missed that part :-) That definitely deserves a tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your `PictureBox` doesn't have `SizeMode` set to `AutoSize`.

Anchoring changes the size, if it's autosized it won't change anything

Also, make 100% sure your `PictureBox` is actually a child of the panel. It's easy to check: select it on the designer and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, it should select the panel.

## Update

As per the comments, seems the problem is that you are anchoring to all the sides (thus producing the **scaling** of the control).

If you want a panel that scales with the form, and controls within the panel that are centered but not scaled along, then anchor that panel to all sides, place the controls inside the panel centered in the designer, and set their anchors to `None`, that way they won't scale, and since they are not anchored, they will move along when the panel scales (but they won't scale with it, which -seems- it's what you are aiming at)

Comment: I made some progress from your answer. So my `PictureBox` started moving now as it should. Except when I make my form bigger it starts sinking into a white area. I updated the question with an image. Please take a look!

Comment: I can't foresee how you have set up your form. Anchoring anchors to the parent control, and it works just fine (I just made a quick project to test).

I don't know what's going on in your form, how have you laid your controls on it, so I can't really help you, I can only "guess"

Comment: Glad it worked, however next time, please add what you are trying to achieve in the question, it'll be easier for the rest so we don't have to guess it... I could have made a one-liner answer immediately :-)